# Excluding a jar in catalina.properties

Tags: tomcat, classpath

I have a `foobar.jar` in my `WEB-INF/lib`'s webapp.

Now, as in the Tomcat `common/lib` there is a jar named `foo.jar` that has a class
with the same name, I want to exclude it.

How can I exclude a jar from being loaded while starting a tomcat ?
Is there an expression I can pass to the `common.loader` in the `catalina.properties` ?

Regards.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I need this, too! The best I can think of is list the JARs you *do* want to include in conf/catalina.properties instead of the directory they're in.

Comment: @reinierpost, Did you find a way to exclude the jar? I need this solution as well.

Comment: @ssasi: Sort of. Thanks for reminding me to post it - see my "answer".

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with was the following ridiculous workaround:

Our Ubuntu server now has the following code in `/etc/default/tomcat7`:

```
forbidden_jar=/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/commons-dbcp.jar
[ -r $forbidden_jar ] && mv $forbidden_jar $forbidden_jar.OFF
```

That way, upgrading the `tomcat7` package (which will reinstall the forbidden jar, and then, presumably, restart Tomcat, which will execute `/etc/default/tomcat7`) won't break our web application (Sakai), like it used to.